# ActiveRecord equivalent of liquibase runOnChange

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a couple of stored procs in a Ruby application that change somewhat frequently.

To update them, I have to create a new migration every time (laborious process of looking up the last migration, copying the procs over to the new one and making minor tweaks).

In a similar situation on a Java project using liquibase, I was able to do the following:

```
<changeSet id="change stored procs" author="some-dude" dbms="postgresql" runOnChange="true">
    <sqlFile
            splitStatements="false"
            stripComments="false"
            path="stored-procs.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

which basically runs the sql file every time it changes (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html).

Is there an ActiveRecord equivalent of liquibase's runOnChange functionality? Or some convenient way of doing this in Ruby?